# Unable to inflate a buffer deflated with java.util.zip.Deflater using Apache MINA compression filter

Tags: java, zlib, apache-mina, jzlib

This test:

```
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import org.apache.mina.core.buffer.IoBuffer;
import org.apache.mina.filter.support.Zlib;
import org.junit.*;

public class ZlibTest {
    private Deflater deflater = null;

    private Zlib inflater = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
        deflater.setStrategy(Deflater.DEFAULT_STRATEGY);
        inflater = new Zlib(Zlib.COMPRESSION_MAX, Zlib.MODE_INFLATER);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInflate() throws Exception {
        byte[] compressed = new byte[14];
        deflater.setInput(new byte[] {1});
        deflater.finish();
        int bytesCompressed = deflater.deflate(compressed);
        IoBuffer compressedBuffer = IoBuffer.wrap(compressed, 0, bytesCompressed);
        System.out.println(compressedBuffer);

        IoBuffer byteUncompressed = inflater.inflate(compressedBuffer);
    }
}
```

fails:

```
java.io.IOException: Unknown error. Error code : 1
    at org.apache.mina.filter.support.Zlib.inflate(Zlib.java:136)
    at ZlibTest.testInflate(ZlibTest.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

What is going wrong here?

UPDATE: if I add

```
        case JZlib.Z_STREAM_END:
```

to line 139 in [Zlib.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/mina/trunk/mina-filter-compression/src/main/java/org/apache/mina/filter/compression/Zlib.java?revision=995776&view=markup), it decodes fine.

Comment: What version of mina are you using? The IoBuffer class is in 2.0.2, but there's no filter.support.Zlib class. The mina-filter-compression-2.0.2.jar shows filter.compression.Zlib (which isn't visible according to Eclipse).

Comment: Actually, I copied the source for Zlib for the test (because it isn't public). Just rechecked with the latest version from http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/mina/trunk/mina-filter-compression/src/main/java/org/apache/mina/filter/compression/Zlib.java?revision=995776&view=markup and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4255743 (famous, 13 year old bug - would go to the highschool shortly if it were my kid), the fix has been delivered in Java 7 (at last); indeed, there's a

```
public int deflate(byte[] b, int off, int len, int flush) {
    if (b == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    if (off < 0 || len < 0 || off > b.length - len) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    synchronized (zsRef) {
        ensureOpen();
        if (flush == NO_FLUSH || flush == SYNC_FLUSH ||
            flush == FULL_FLUSH)
            return deflateBytes(zsRef.address(), b, off, len, flush);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

section of code added to Deflater class. So today (2012), you can just stick with java.util if that functionality is all that you need.

Answer (score 2):

You've hit the 'design choice' of the Java Deflater class that caused the creation of JZlib - you can't control the `FLUSH` parameter for zlib.

The output from the Deflater class for your one-byte array of {1}:

```
[0] 120 
[1] -38 
[2] 99  
[3] 4   
[4] 0   
[5] 0   <<
[6] 2   <<
[7] 0   <<
[8] 2   <<
```

The output from the Zlib class when deflating for your one-byte array of {1}:

```
[0] 120 
[1] -38 
[2] 98  
[3] 4   
[4] 0   
[5] 0   <<
[6] 0   <<
[7] -1  <<
[8] -1  <<
```

From [Zlib manual](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html)

> If the parameter flush is set to
>   Z_SYNC_FLUSH, all pending output is
>   flushed to the output buffer and the
>   output is aligned on a byte boundary,
>   so that the decompressor can get all
>   input data available so far. (In
>   particular avail_in is zero after the
>   call if enough output space has been
>   provided before the call.) Flushing
>   may degrade compression for some
>   compression algorithms and so it
>   should be used only when necessary.
>   This completes the current deflate
>   block and follows it with an empty
>   stored block that is three bits plus
>   filler bits to the next byte, **followed
>   by four bytes (00 00 ff ff)**.

From [JZlib - Why JZlib?](http://www.jcraft.com/jzlib/)

> Java Platform API provides packages
>   'java.util.zip.*' for accessing to
>   zlib, but that support is very limited
>   if you need to use the essence of
>   zlib. For example, we needed to full
>   access to zlib to add the packet
>   compression support to pure Java SSH
>   system, but they are useless for our
>   requirements. ...
>
> To implement this
>   functionality, the Z_PARTIAL_FLUSH
>   mode of zlib must be used, however JDK
>   does not permit us to do so. It seems
>   that this problem has been well known
>   and some people have already reported
>   to JavaSoft's BugParade(for example,
>   BugId:4255743), but any positive
>   response has not been returned from
>   JavaSoft, so this problem will not be
>   solved forever. This is our motivation
>   to hack JZlib.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't assume that Zlib and Inflater/deflater use the same data protocol for sending data. They may use the same underlying compression but I suspect Zlib is expecting the stream to contain information for its own used, not just raw data.

---

```
Deflater deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
deflater.setStrategy(Deflater.DEFAULT_STRATEGY);

byte[] compressed = new byte[10];
deflater.setInput(new byte[]{1});
deflater.finish();
int bytesCompressed = deflater.deflate(compressed);
System.out.println("bytesCompressed=" + bytesCompressed + " " + Arrays.toString(compressed));

Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
inflater.setInput(compressed, 0, bytesCompressed);
byte[] decompressed = new byte[2];
int byteDecompressed = inflater.inflate(decompressed);

System.out.println("bytesInflated=" + byteDecompressed + " " + Arrays.toString(decompressed));
```

prints

```
bytesCompressed=9 [120, -38, 99, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0]
bytesInflated=1 [1, 0]
```

Comment: Documentation for `Deflater` specifically says "Compressed data will be generated in ZLIB format" (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#Deflater%28int%29).

Comment: As I said, they use the same underlying format. But they may not use them in exactly the same way. If these were idenical, why would MINA have a seperate class for this?

Comment: `java.util.zip.*` is just a wrapper over the native zlib (see http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/zip/Deflater.java.htm) (and I can check that compressing data using the Erlang `zlib` module produces the same result as `Deflater`). JZlib page says "Needless to say, JZlib can inflate data, which is deflated by zlib". So it seems that it must be either a bug in JZlib or I am misusing it in some way.